# Dynamic anchor tag to DIV but CSS click is not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have code snippet like below I am facing problem when I click on the links i.e 1,2,3,4 numbers click was not working ... nothing is happening.

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var number = 0;
        number = number+1;

        var numhtml = "<a href='#' rel='"+number+"'>"+number+"</a>"
        $("#slidenumbers").append(numhtml);

        $(".paging a").click(function() {   
            $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
            //Reset Timer
            clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
            rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
            rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
            return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
        }); 

    });
</script>

<div class="paging" id="slidenumbers"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.paging a {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #DAF3F8;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.paging a.active {
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: #5DC9E1; 
    border: 1px solid gray;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.paging a:hover {
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

**ERROR:**

When I click on the link nothing is happening. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Who downvoted this? this is a perfectly well explained question, with good example code. Stop being an idiot.

Comment: @Baszz the issue isnt with HTML the links are generated in the script to there is enough to work with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions when adding elements dynamically:

```
$(".paging a").live('click', function() {   
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the `click()` handler only attaches events to DOM elements which are available on load. Because you're appending elements dynamically, you need to attach events using either `on()` if you're using jQuery 1.7+, or `delegate()` if 1.6 or earlier.

jQuery 1.7+:

```
$(".paging").on('click', 'a', function() {   
    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
    //Reset Timer
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});
```

jQuery 1.6 or earlier:

```
$(".paging").delegate('click', 'a', function() {   
    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
    //Reset Timer
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click event won't fire on elements that have been dynamically added to the DOM, you need `live` or `on` or `delegate`

```
$(".paging").on('click', 'a', function() {
```

or

```
$("a .paging").live("click", function() {
```